# Reading video file metadata with ruby

Tags: ruby, video, metadata

I am working on a app and I let users to upload videos.
The problem is I need to get the width and height of the videos after users submitted the form, but couldn't find a way to do it.

Users can upload any video type, avi, mpeg, mov, flv..

I just need to get width and height metadata of the video, but so far I couldn't find a ruby function or a gem.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [streamio-ffmpeg](https://rubygems.org/gems/streamio-ffmpeg). It seems to be maintained and relatively up to date.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [mediainfo gem](https://github.com/greatseth/mediainfo)

it will get you the width and height. I've implemented it this way, where filename is the path to the file you'd like to inpsect:

```
%x[mediainfo --Inform="Video;%Width%" filename]
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the [rvideo gem](http://rvideo.rubyforge.org/), but whether or not it's suitable depends on whether or not you can install [FFmpg](http://ffmpeg.org/) (and flvtool for Flash).

Comment: thanks for the rvideo but unfortunately I cannot install FFmpg to the server

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like rvideo project is abandoned.